# Realizar consulta y obtenerla con las relaciones eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy haciendo una consulta en laravel pero no me esta dando su relacion de uno a muchos, aqui dejo la consulta y el modelo

> Modelo Article

```
class Article extends Model
{

    protected $with = ['category'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'register_number',
        'name',
        'quantity',
        'category_id',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function setNameAttribute($value) {
        $this->attributes['name'] = strtolower($value);
    }

    public function getNameAttribute($value) {
        return ucwords($value);
    }

}
```

y aqui dejo la consulta que estoy realizando, como se ve anteriomente tengo el atributo with que deberia traer la categoria

```
$articles = DB::table('articles')
            ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $start_date)
            ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $end_date)
            ->get();
```

me da al final todos los articulos pero no me da tambien la categoria

> ejm: una lista de articulos asi:

```
{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Prueba",
            "register_number": "95ee89fb-bd27-3249-a7d2-086abc57919e",
            "quantity": 66,
            "category_id": 3,
            "created_at": "2019-07-10 05:37:27",
            "updated_at": "2019-08-11 15:59:40",
            "category": {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "quos",
                "created_at": "2019-08-10 05:37:27",
                "updated_at": "2019-08-10 05:37:27"
            }
        }
```

Comment: ¿Quieres obtener de una categoría todos sus productos?

Comment: no, estoy obteniendo todos los articulos restringiendo la fecha de creacion, pero quiero que me la de con su relacion de category

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que el detalle de que no funcione la relación que estas estableciendo con Eloquent en tu modelo, es por que estás usando el queryBuilder, pues al hacer uso del método `table()` estas indicando que directo haga una consulta sobre esa tabla y como no invocas al modelo `Article` no mostrará las categorías con las que el producto se encuentra asociado

Tu consulta debería partir de este modo:

```
$article = Article::with('category')
                  ->whereDate('created_at', '>=', $start_date)
                  ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $end_date)
                  ->get();
```

Donde hacemos uso de *eager loading* para que en la misma consulta se carguen las categorías producto de usar la relación `belongsTo()` declarada en el cuerpo de la clase del modelo Article, donde pasaremos el nombre de esta misma como argumento del método `with()`

- [`Eager loading`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: Gracias amigo, ya te doy el check!